# Repeat values in x-axis matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, line-plot

I'm trying to create a plot about crimes in my city per 100000 inhabitants (the plot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvAXy.jpg) above), x-axis is the year of the crime and y-axis the crime per 100000 inhabitants. I've a problem with x-axis because it repeat the years. How can i avoid it? I want to each year only show up a time.

[image: Crimenes]

Code:

```
data = xlsread('Pico.xls');
x  = [2012 2013 2014 2015 2016];
plot( x,data(2,:),'-C',x, data(3,:),'-V',x, data(4,:),'-V',x, data(5,:),'-V')
xtickformat('%i')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the *x*-axis ticks equal to the values in your `x` variable. To achieve that, add this after your code:

```
set(gca, 'xtick', x)
```